# Verb related to confidence that means unconvincing

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Please help me find the correct verb to fill in the blank:

> His actions don't ..... confidence.

I think it means that his actions do little or none to convince others.

Comment: If you want to talk about how he fails to inspire others you might say "Instill.". As in, his actions don't instill confidence in others.  If instead you want to talk about his lack of confidence you could use "exude.". As in, his actions don't exude confidence.

Comment: Or you could just use *inspire* itself—if the subject of the confidence is himself. What is it that he is making others confident *of*?

Comment: How many letters?

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic expression is to *inspire* confidence.

**[inspire confidence](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/inspire)** (ldoceonline)

> (=make people feel confident because they trust your ability)
>    - His driving hardly inspires confidence.
>    - The hospital’s record does not inspire confidence.

Answer (score 0):

The other potential word is:

**Invigorate** (adjective) [<sub>OED</sub>](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/invigorate)

> *Meaning:* Give strength or energy to.
>
> > *Usage:* Trump press conference failed to *invigorate* confidence in achieving stronger growth in the USA[1](http://cn.wit-invest.com/trump_press_conference_failed_to_invigorate_confidence_in_achieving_stronger_growth_in_the_usa_-_ampgfx).

Your sentence,

> > His actions don't *invigorate* confidence.